# Openlayers and openstreetmap plot the route incorrectly

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have a WebView vehicle tracking application. I completed everything, but I could not manage to draw the path. What is the problem here?

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector(),
  url_osrm_nearest = '//router.project-osrm.org/nearest/v1/driving/',
    url_osrm_route = '//router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/',
    icon_url = '//cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/ol3/master/examples/data/icon.png',
    vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: vectorSource
    }),
    styles = {
      route: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          width: 6, color: [40, 40, 40, 0.8]
        })
      }),
      icon: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 1],
          src: icon_url
        })
      })
    };
var utils = {
  getNearest: function(coord){

    var coord4326 =coord;    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      //make sure the coord is on street

      fetch(url_osrm_nearest + coord4326.join()).then(function(response) { 
        // Convert to JSON
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(json) {
        if (json.code === 'Ok') resolve(json.waypoints[0].location);
        else reject();
      });
    });
  },
  createFeature: function(coord) {
    feature = new ol.Feature({
      type: 'place',
      geometry: new ol.geom.Point(coord)
    });
    //feature.setStyle(iconStyle3);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
  },
  createRoute: function(polyline) {

    var route = new ol.format.Polyline({
factor: 1e5,
    }).readGeometry(polyline);
    feature = new ol.Feature({
      type: 'route',
      geometry: route
    });
    feature.setStyle(styles.route);
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
  },
  to4326: function(coord) {
    return ol.proj.transform([
      parseFloat(coord[0]), parseFloat(coord[1])
    ]);
  }
};
view = new ol.View({
  center: [34.061624811814305,39.44893665949777],
  zoom: 16,
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
});
const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM(),
    }),
      vectorLayer
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: view,
});
const markerEl = document.getElementById('geolocation_marker');
const marker = new ol.Overlay({
  positioning: 'center-center',
  element: markerEl,
  stopEvent: false
});

  map.addOverlay(marker);

const markerEl2 = document.getElementById('geolocation_marker_musteri');
const marker2 = new ol.Overlay({
  positioning: 'center-center',
  element: markerEl2,
  stopEvent: false
});

  map.addOverlay(marker2);

const positions = new ol.geom.LineString([], ('XYZM'));
feature.getGeometry().setCoordinates([longi_,lati_]);  
          utils.getNearest([longi_,lati_]);
          utils.getNearest([longi__v,lati_]);    
          utils.createFeature([longi__v,lati_]);
          var point1 = [longi_,lati_];
          var point2 = [longi__v,lati_];
          fetch(url_osrm_route + point1 + ';' + point2).then(function(r) { 
            return r.json();
          }).then(function(json) {
            if(json.code !== 'Ok') {              
              return;
            }      
            utils.createRoute(json.routes[0].geometry);
```

It draws a path as follows.

[image: Example route]

I'm looking at the route in openstreetmap with the same coordinates. It gives the correct route there. By the way, the coordinates are someone dynamic, that is, the position of the device. The other coordinate is stationary.

Edit:

I've realized now. It draws a straight line between two points. It doesn't draw according to the road.

Answer (score 1):

I tried hard and couldn't find the solution. I also used openrouteservice instead of osm for geometry.

```
function get_JSON(coor1,coor2)
{
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('POST', "https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car/json");

  request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8');
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'api_key');
  request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
      var data_json= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      utils.createRoute(data_json.routes[0].geometry);
    }
  };
  const body = '{"coordinates":[['+coor1+'],['+coor2+']],"radiuses":120000}';
  request.send(body);
}
```