# Routing in openlayers map

Tags: angular, openstreetmap, openlayers-6

[Map Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxIr6.jpg) I am using an openlayers map in angular. I need to add routes between multiple placemarkers and coordinates will be coming from a API. Can anyone suggest any way to implement it?

Comment: is it the same what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70590799/2533926

Comment: Yes i have coordinates of source and destination. I need suggestions on how can I achieve routing between those coordinates. Also, unpaid options would be great.

Comment: I have attached image for reference.